# Where is the cuda folder?

Tags: ubuntu, cudnn

I download the cudaa using the .deb from the official website and follow the guidance to download other files by apt-get. But I can't find cuda folder in /usr/local.
Here is my order used.

```
sudo dpkg -i cudnn-local-repo-${OS}-8.x.x.x_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cudnn-local-repo-${OS}-8.x.x.x_1.0-1_arm64.deb
sudo cp /var/cudnn-local-repo-*/cudnn-local-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8=8.x.x.x-1+cudaX.Y
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8-dev=8.x.x.x-1+cudaX.Y
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8-samples=8.x.x.x-1+cudaX.Y
```

And my system is the latest Ubuntu.

Or whether use this way will hurt my computer? maybe I can use .tar to reinstall.

I tried the find order but failed.
I tried `whereis cuda`, but cudaa is not in those folder `cuda: /usr/lib/cuda /usr/include/cuda`

`whereis` output nothing when I ask the cudnn and libcudnn.